# Extreme values of a Brownian random variable with constant drift

Tags: stochastic-calculus, maxima-minima

Consider a stochastic differential equation such as
$dX = C\, dt + \sigma\, dB$
With a condition such as $X(0)=0$. I consider this variable across the time interval $[0,1]$. Calculating the distribution of X(1) is trivial, but I'm trying to understand the behavior of min(X) and max(X). (I believe this is from what is known as extremal calculus, but I don't know any and couldn't find a simple reference.) I do know of course that from the odd time symmetry, the distributions follow

$\min(X) \sim \mu - \max(X)$

Now while I'm sure that this is a solved problem, I'm curious how the correlations between the minimum and maximum behave. I expect that for large mu (equiv: large time) they become less and less correlated.

Comment: Do you already know how to compute the distribution of the max and min?

Comment: No. That would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I should be more precise: do you know how to compute the distribution of the max and min *separately*, not their joint distribution? This is a simpler matter; the result (with $C=0$) is at least stated on the Wikipedia article for the Wiener process, and I think you can find it in a typical reference on stochastic differential equations.

Comment: I also found a presentation on Google: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=27&ved=0ahUKEwjPv_qt8_XNAhUHLB4KHYG3CuU4FBAWCEwwBg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uchicago.edu%2F~may%2FVIGRE%2FVIGRE2010%2FREUPapers%2FDahl.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE-Izx4zLkKQ-3cTeY0niRWpj0M2w&sig2=Uw_ENN2wLZ2eb5MnwC2nAA&bvm=bv.127178174,d.dmo&cad=rja Proposition 7.